# Voice control: disable dictation mode

Tags: voice-control

I'm using Voice Control on my laptop, and I'm facing an issue. Whenever I have the cursor in a writable area (e.g. Visual Studio Code, Skype or Slack chat prompts, etc.), the dictation mode starts writing random words. This happens when I'm listening to music or video tutorials, and it becomes frustrating to delete the unintended text.

Is there any way to use only the command mode and avoid this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While using **Voice Control**, speaking the command ***"Show Me What To Say"***, will open the **Voice Commands** window.

[image]

Now I can see what my options are.  So if you don't want **Dictation** randomly inserting words, just speak the phrase ***"Command mode"***.  Now **Voice Control** will only be listening for actual commands (built-in system commands and any custom commands) and will perform its associated actions when it identifies a spoken voice command.  Then when you need to do any typing, just speak the command ***"Dictation mode"***.